# How to control HD video play position and speed in XNA?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, performance, video, xna

I am developing a game for Windows in **C# using Visual Studio 2010** and **XNA 4.0**. I would like to be able to set and change the play position of an HD video and also play the video in reverse, depending on user input.

I am having trouble finding where to start. XNA's videoPlayer class does not provide these type of functions. I've read that XNA DirectShow is now out of date  and slow when using HD video.

I don't quite understand how I would be able to use or implement tools such as ffmpeg with my project. It seems some people have had similar questions and posted solutions but without much detail. These are below.

- interop out to talk to the core DX functionality.
- write a managed c++ wrapper to interop ffmpeg.
- write an mpeg decoder.

I am not sure what would be best and where to begin.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VideoPlayer class has a "PlayPosition" property, which you should be able to play with.

Otherwise (and I don't know how big your video file is nor how long) try an image sequence and animate the current image sequence and control that with user input. Of course working with image sequences would make audio reversal (if there is audio) etc very complicated.

Last but not least, you can see if you can figure anything out from this mpeg decoder here:
https://www.box.com/shared/ojzfv0qzfx

Something else that might help with mpeg decoding:
http://chrisa.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/decoding-mpeg2-information/